# How can I make my html page search engine friendly

Tags: html

I am new to seo. I have tried using different methods to get rank in search engine. But my page is not getting search engine friendly. What should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Text to Your Images, Flash and Videos. ...
Create Relevant Title Tags. ...
Use Straight HTML Navigation Links on Your Website. ...
Eliminate Apparent Content Duplication. ...
Remove Hidden Text.